# How to concatenate this below:

Tags: php, loops

I need help on concatenation. I have a Title which is displayed below like this:

```
<h1>: SESSION (<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

In words the above coding could read like this:

```
Session(ABB) 1 OF 2
```

Now Imagine I am creating 2 exams ($_SESSION['initial_count'] = ‘2’), both exams only have 1 question. I want the database to INSERT the VALUES like below:

```
 Session Id   Question
    ABB1            Who are you
    ABB2            Who am I
```

As you can see above exam ‘ABB1’ which is the first exam which has its own question and exam ‘ABB2’ which is second exam has its own question.

BUT if there is only 1 exam, then I do not want the ‘1’ to be displayed next to the

SessionId, like below:

```
Session Id   Question
ABB            Who are you
```

So how can I concatenate so that if `$_SESSION['initial_count'] = ‘1’` then do not include the number 1 next to the sessioId, else if there are multiple `$_SESSION['initial_count']`, then concatenate the `$sessionMinus` number next to `SessionId`?

Below is the code where I want the concatenation to occur.

```
foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
{
    $insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . "' , ' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) . "', ' ".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) . "'";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operator is your friend.

```
$insertquestion[] = $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $sessionMinus : '') ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
$sessionId = $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION_['initial_count'] > 1 ? $sessionMinus : '');
echo '<h1> : SESSION ' . $sessionId . ' of ' . $_SESSION_['initial_count'];
```

Comment: I want the concatenation to occur in the $insertquestion[] variable.

Comment: Like that `mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION_['initial_count'] > 1 ? $sessionMinus : ''))` ?